# check if screen lock has passcode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Can someone help me if it is possible to get information about lock screen passcode in windows phone 8.

I need to know if the user have set a password on lock screen or not. Depending on this setting I am going to change program behaviour to add more security.

Comment: Don't post the same question over and over....

Comment: @AMR - The other question was for `WP7`, and someone suggested in the comments to ask another question for `WP8`

Comment: @manojlds all of these windows phone tags make me want to slam my face against my keyboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is currently no API available which will tell you whether the user has set a PIN on the lock screen from within an app.

Answer copied from same previous questions.